# getting Rich Api error at context.sync() when trying to insert html into a content control using InsertHtml method

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-web-addins

i am trying to insert the below html into a content control 
using word api i am getting Richapi error at content.sync()

html Code with checkbox:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type='checkbox'/>
<p>Click the checkbox</p>
</body>
</html>
```

html code without checkbox:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>Test Html</p>
</body>
</html>
```

code used to insert html into Content Control:

```
function InsertHtml() {
        Word.run(function (context) {

            var Html = "<html><head></head><body><input type='checkbox' />click on check box</body></html>";
            var DynamicControl = context.document.contentControls.getByTag("Test").getFirstOrNullObject();

            DynamicControl.insertHtml(Html, Word.InsertLocation.replace);     

            return context.sync().then(function () {
                {
                   write('Inserted HTML in the first content control.');
                }

            });
        })
            .catch(errorHandler);
    }
```

with this code i am getting below error at context.sync()

GeneralException: GeneralException

```
   at Anonymous function (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:24:287994)
   at T (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:24:220903)
   at x (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:24:220989)
   at t (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:24:220797)
   at l (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:24:219304)
```

Same code is working as expected with html which doesnt have any control like Checkbox,Textbox ,text area

Comment: What happens if you try inserting the HTML to a range that's not a content control? Does it work, or do you get the same error?

Comment: @CindyMeister i am getting same error, i tried inserting the HTML in document body as well i am getting same error

Comment: In that case, I'd say the reason for the error is that Word simply does not *support* inserting HTML controls. Word's native file format is *not* HTML, it's Office Open XML (Word Open XML). A converter is required to insert HTML into a Word document. Quite likely, the converter used by the Office JS API does not "understand" the HTML controls. You'd need to either strip them out or replace them with something innocuous that code can later find and insert a corresponding Content Control.